# How to rewrite python codes which class has many @property?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I have write my class with many `@property` inside, and *Python Cookbook* suggest this is bad code. I decided to rewrite my code to remove those `@property`, here is example in *Python Cookbook* shows how to rewrite class without using `@property` and still have `setter, getter`.

```
class Integer(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        else:
            return instance.__dict__[self.name]

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if not isinstance(value, int):
            raise TypeError('int expected')
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = value

    def __delete__(self, instance):
        del instance.__dict__[self.name]

class Point(object):
    x = Integer('x')
    y = Integer('y')

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

Here I show my code **before** rewrite.
**In brief**, my code will format text in MS-Word by using `python-docx` library, so you can see I need to apply text format(bold, italic...) by code like `self._run.bold = value` while setting `self._bold` by `self._bold = value` . This means I need **more than** just set the attribute value compare to *Python Cookbook* example.

```
class CellParagraph(object):
    def __init__(self, cell, text=None):
    self._cell = cell
    self._style = 'Default Paragraph Font'
    self._paragraph = self._cell.paragraphs[0]
    self._run = self._paragraph.add_run(text, style=self._style)
    self._font_name = None
    self._bold = False
    self._italic = False
    ...many of them...

    @property
    def bold(self):
        return self._bold

    @bold.setter
    def bold(self, value):
        self._run.bold = value
        self._bold = value

    @property
    def italic(self):
        return self._italic

    @italic.setter
    def italic(self, value):
        self._run.italic = value
        self._italic = value

    ...many of them...
```

Here is my code **after** rewrite. You can see I have to write `refresh` method to apply those format to MS-Word, I have to use `refresh()` every time I set some text format.
My question:**How to rewrite code like my case to *Python Cookbook* example style?**
Any discussion will be appreciate.

```
class AddAttrb(object):
    def __init__(self, name, Etype=None):
        self.name = name
        self.Etype = Etype

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        else:
            return instance.__dict__[self.name]

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if self.Etype:
            if not isinstance(value, self.Etype):
                raise TypeError('Need to be type: {}.'.format(self.Etype))
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = value

    def __delete__(self, instance):
        del instance.__dict__[self.name]


class CellParagraph(object):


    bold = AddAttrb('bold', bool)
    italic = AddAttrb('italic', bool)
    underline = AddAttrb('underline', bool)
    ...many more...

    def __init__(self, cell, text=None, style='Default Paragraph Font', font=None, bold=False, italic=False, underline=False,
             font_color=None, size=0, alignment='center'):
        self._paragraph = self._cell.paragraphs[0]
        self._run = self._paragraph.add_run(text, style=self.style)
        self.font = font
        self.bold = bold
        self.italic = italic
        ...many more...

    def refresh(self):
        self._run.bold = self.bold
        self._run.italic = self.italic
        self._run.underline = self.underline
        ...many more...
```

Comment: What specific reason does the Cookbook cite for `@property` being bad…?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/314986). This seems like a good use of `@property` to me, too.

Comment: If you're going to post Python code, you should probably indent it in a way that makes sense.

Comment: @khelwood indent correctly now, thanks.

Comment: @deceze I am using Chinese version of _Python Cookbook_ , My translation of the reasons: Too many repeated codes, easy to cause errors, not looks good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to both set the `_property` itself, and the `_run._property`,

## Edit:

> I noticed a bug, and the state of the `TextProperty` was shared
>   between the different paragraphs. So the value needs to be set on the
>   `CellParagraph` instead of the `TextProperty`
>
> Using the `setattr(instance, f"_{self.name}", value)` and variations
>   dynamically generates the `_bold` attribute on the paragraph. So take
>   care not to use any of these yourself

You can use the [Descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) pattern used in the cookbook using `setattr` to change the value on the `CellParagraph._run`

```
class TextProperty(object):
    def __init__(self, name, property_type=None):
        self.name = name
        self.property_type = property_type

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return getattr(instance, f"_{self.name}")

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if self.property_type is not None and not isinstance(
            value, self.property_type
        ):
            raise TypeError(f"{self.name} needs to be of type: {self.property_type}.")
        print(f"setting {self.name} to {value}")
        setattr(instance, f"_{self.name}", value)
        setattr(instance._run, self.name, value)

    def __delete__(self, instance):
        del instance.__dict__[self.name]
        delattr(instance, f"_{self.name}")
        delattr(instance._run, self.name)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "TextProperty("\
                    f"name={self.name}, "\
                    f"value={self.value}, "\
                    f"property_type={self.property_type}"\
                ")"
```

Then I used a dummy `Run` class, to act as the `paragraph._run` attribute

```
class Run:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bold = None
        self.italic = None

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Run(bold={self.bold}, italic={self.italic})"
```

you can use this like this in your `CellParagraph` class (simplified):

```
class CellParagraph(object):
    bold = TextProperty("bold", bool)
    italic = TextProperty("italic")

    def __init__(self, bold=False, italic=False):
        self._run = Run()
        self.bold = bold
        self.italic = italic

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"CellParagraph(bold={self.bold}, italic={self.italic})"
```

then create some paragraphs to test this behaviour:

```
paragraph_1 = CellParagraph()
paragraph_2 = CellParagraph(italic=True)
```

> ```
> setting bold to False
> setting italic to False
> setting bold to False
> setting italic to True
> ```

```
(paragraph_1, paragraph_1._run), (paragraph_2, paragraph_2._run)
```

> ```
> ((CellParagraph(bold=False, italic=False), Run(bold=False, italic=False)),
>  (CellParagraph(bold=False, italic=True), Run(bold=False, italic=True)))
> ```

```
paragraph_1.bold = True
paragraph_1, paragraph_1._run
```

> ```
> setting bold to True
>
> (CellParagraph(bold=True, italic=False), Run(bold=True, italic=False))
> ```

```
paragraph_1.italic = 'abc'
paragraph_1.bold = 'abc'
```

> ```
> setting italic to abc
> TypeError: bold needs to be of type: <class 'bool'>.
> ```

If you have a lot of attributes that need to be changed both on the paragraph and on the `paragraph._run`, then using this pattern can save some boilerplate, but it is less explicit that using the `@property`s